# how do i find last value i can jump to in a listView.builder?

Tags: flutter

basically I need to be able to know if a value is larger then the length of a listView.builder and if i can jump to it or if its outside the list. any way of doing it? I tried getting this value from the controller but I cant find anything that would help me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, could you post some code to make it easier to help you?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood about your question this is the answer you are probably looking for:

Here I have created a function named createList which will create a list and will compare the value with the length of the list.

```
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  final int value = 7;

  Widget createList(int count) {
    if (value > count) {
      //Your code
      //print("The value is greater than count");
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
          child: Container(
            height: 30,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: createList(5),
    );
  }
}
```